# Eclipse Subversion export local changed file list

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm using Eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 2 and Subclipse from Tigris.

I don't see the way to export a list of the last local modified files that are not yet commited.

I want to do this before commiting the changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Why? You can always get that information from the SVN history.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't yet commit the las changes, so don't have that information in SVN's history. Anyway, I finally decided to do first the commit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the commit dialog (right click -> Team -> Commit) select all the files (CTRL+A) and then right click on one and select `Paste Selected Names`. This will paste the file names in the comment area and you can copy them from there.

Comment: I don't see the "Paste Selected Names" option.

Comment: hm ok, I'm using Kepler maybe this option is not present in Helios.

Answer (score 0):

Using Subversive...

Open Synchronize view

Right click on a change set or project.

Extract All...

This will save a list of all the files in the selected change set or project